# Change Info in Word from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a letter in Word that needs to be sent out to a number of contacts [(example of letter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8wsW.png). The only thing that needs to change in the letter is the recipients information 
[(example of how recipients info is stored)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfDy6.png), but I don't know what the best way to change this info is.

I did a little bit of research and what I've come across is that people either do a search and replace or use fields. I suspect that there is a better method than search and replace since I know exactly where the text needs to change. I'm thinking there might be something similar to named ranges like in excel?

Now this is where I came across fields, but to be honest I don't really understand them. I know they have a name but this whole equation thing throws me off. So my question is how do I change this information in the quickest/most efficient way?

I understand how to access and save word documents and am planning on using a loop to go through each row of contacts one by one, so if you have a solution you can leave that part out (unless you know of a better way!).

Comment: Why not do Mail Merge in Word? You can use an Excel Sheet that has the names/info you need, and a Mail Merge could quickly generate these letters...See [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3) for instance.

Comment: That works great! I did not know that existed.